# Unzip a raw file within memory in R

Tags: r, zip

I need to download a zipped csv file from internet, unzip it and load it into memory as data.frame. Is there a way I can finish the whole process in memory only without reading/writing the disk? Here's what I tried:

```
library(RCurl)
file <- getURL(url, userpwd='user:pwd')
tf <- tempfile()
writeBin(content(file, "raw"), tf)
tf <- unzip(tf, exdir=tempdir())
data <- read.csv(tf)
unlink(tf)
```

I think `writeBin`, `unzip` and `read.csv` here use expensive disk I/O, but I don't know how to improve it.

Comment: I would be very surprised that the latency involved with writing and unzipping the file is slower than the initial download?  But you might try the `unz()` function.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens, can you explain more about how you use `unz` function to do this task? It's not trivial to me.

Comment: Use vroom for this. https://vroom.r-lib.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this example using `unz()` gets you somewhere closer by opening a connection to a single file within your Zip archive, though I would be surprised if the `unz()` function doesn't actually unzip to disk, I haven't checked it:

```
##  Create a sample data.frame object:
d <- data.frame(a=rnorm(40), b=rnorm(40))

##  Write this data.frame to two separate CSV files, and zip
##    them together into a new archive:
write.csv(d, file="d.csv")
write.csv(d, file="d_2.csv")
zip("d.zip", c("d.csv", "d_2.csv"))

##  In this case, we will open a file connection to a single file 
##    inside the zip archive, and read the data in using read.csv():
f <- unz("d.zip", "d_2.csv")
a <- read.csv( f )
head(a)
```

Comment: On my Win 7 system `zip` function gives `Warning message:
running command '"zip" -r9X "d.zip" "d.csv" "d_2.csv" ' had status 127`, then `unz` cannot open the connection. Is it a reproducible error?

Comment: Well, you must not have a Zip application installed that is available in the system PATH... You can either install Rtools and make sure that `Rtools/bin` is in your PATH (which you can check running the following, `shell("PATH")`) or just test the function on your own Zip file instead of creating it using my script?

Comment: I tried and it seems that unz won't unzip to disk but I still can't make it extract data from url instead of local zip file, especially in my case with username and password and they both have '@' that confuses url parser.

Comment: Of course you'd have to download the file first? You can't unzip something from a non-local file?

Comment: Yes I can download the file using `getURL`, and it's downloaded directly into memory, I wonder how I can unzip the `file` variable in my example and parse it to `data.frame` without having to write it to disk as local file. `unz` seems to work only with local file but not the raw binary file in memory.

Comment: Seems like you'll need to write it to disk then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the extra unzip.  Use the tidyverse function `read_csv()`.
Files ending in .zip or .gz will be automatically uncompressed.

You can also avoid the tempfile with this function.  Filenames starting with https:// or ftp:// will be automatically downloaded.